# congruence problem: $ \Pi_{n=2}^{n=99} (1-n^2+n^4) mod(101) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

can someone please help to give me some pointers how to solve this problem I came across.

$$ \prod_{n=2}^{99} (1-n^2+n^4) \pmod{101} $$

I am unable to solve it analytically but wolfarm alpha is giving me an answer equal to 9.